# cannot start mongod for the website. "Unable to lock the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock "

Tags: mongodb

I am getting an error every time I try to run mongod over my system. I even tried killing the mongod process and then starting. Doesnt work.
Following is the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtPeS.png

Comment: Yes that worked !! thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens when the mongo didn't have a clean shutdown, so it is simply a forced shutdown + repair.

If you are using linux, just follow this instructions:

- First make sure the mongo is not running: `systemctl mongod stop`
- Remove the previous lock file: `rm /data/db/mongod.lock`
- Run the mongod repair: `mongod --repair`
- If needed, close the running mongod and restart the mongod: `systemctl mongod start`